# File download failed in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, download

I am trying to download file from `src` folder in my react app, but file download is failing

file import

```
import test from "../../test.json";
```

download

```
  const link = document.createElement("a");
  link.href = test;
  link.setAttribute("download", `test.json`);
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
```

File download failed
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can not download files in the src folder.
If you need this file and change it in every build, you can use a script and run it before building for copying files from src to the public folder. If not, you must copy the file to the public folder.